# Issue while adding in ldap

Tags: ldap, openldap

I am getting an issue while adding user into an OpenLDAP server.

```
dn: uid=ldapuser1,ou=People,dc=infra,dc=com
uid: ldapuser1
cn: ldapuser1
sn: ldapuser1
mail: ldapuser1@ABC.com
mailRoutingAddress: ldapuser1@ABC.com
mailHost: mail.ABC.com
objectClass: inetLocalMailRecipient
objectClass: person
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: top
objectClass: kerberosSecurityObject
objectClass: shadowAccount
userPassword: {crypt}$6$JNpQAF00$y9tYggGaYWlKfPqhx.
shadowLastChange: 16947
shadowMax: 99999
shadowWarning: 7
krbName: ldapuser1@ABC.COM
loginShell: /bin/bash
uidNumber: 534
gidNumber: 537
homeDirectory: /home/ldapuserdir/ldapuser1
```

While executing below command it's giving error

```
ldapadd -x -W -D "cn=Manager,dc=infra,dc=com" -f /etc/openldap/users.ldif

Enter LDAP Password:
adding new entry "uid=ldapuser1,ou=People,dc=infra,dc=com"
ldap_add: Invalid syntax (21)
        additional info: objectClass: value #6 invalid per syntax
```

Schema Included:

```
include         /etc/openldap/schema/corba.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/core.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/cosine.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/duaconf.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/dyngroup.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/inetorgperson.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/java.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/misc.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/nis.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/openldap.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/ppolicy.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/collective.schema
```

How this can be solved? Let me know if more details required.

Answer (score 0):

Numbering the attributes from zero, #6 is `kerberosSecurityObject`, which isn't present in any of those schemas.

Comment: It is working how? You loaded another schema? You should provide an answer to your question, or delete it.

Comment: I have removed that object class because i am not using it and it's working. And it was weekend and i don't touch my laptop, so replying today.